# Examples for Propagation Required and Requires_new

Tags: java, spring, transactions, isolation-level

We have different propagation levels like Required and Requires_new etc.

What are the real-time examples like when to use Required vs Requires_new?

I know how these propagation works, I am looking for practical examples.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of different use cases for you...

- Recording all requests to the database.
- Adding a new row to the database because of another transaction, but no matter what you still want the the new row if the parent transaction fails.

We did the second one for our web application's access metrics.  If needed, we would add a new User Agent in its own table even if the write to the access table failed.